# How could I get and set values with Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I'm new at Vue and this is the first time that I use Vuex, so this could be a completly misunderstanding of my part.

I have a page that have 2 DatePicker, when the user select the values, the page should pass the values to another page that will make a POST to a WebService. I read that for do that I'll need to use Vuex, so I tried, but I can't set the value of my var to the Vuex var.
Here's my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/y0ovmqrqlv

And here's the code (present in Data.vue) where I try to set the value:

```
methods: {
getDatePrimeiro(primeiraDataPassada) {
  var dataUm = primeiraDataPassada;
  this.primeiraData = new Date(
    dataUm.getTime() - dataUm.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000
  )
    .toISOString()
    .split("T")[0];
  console.log(this.primeiraData);
},
getDateSegundo(segundaDataPassada) {
  var dataDois = segundaDataPassada;
  this.segundaData = new Date(
    dataDois.getTime() - dataDois.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000
  )
    .toISOString()
    .split("T")[0];
  console.log(this.segundaData);
  this.retornar;
}
  },

computed: {
    retornar() {
      console.log("Entrou função", this.primeiraData, this.segundaData)
      this.$store.state.primeiraData = this.primeiraData;
      this.$store.state.segundaData = this.segundaData;
    }
  }
```

Please help me.

Comment: In the codesandbox page you've shared, I've found no functional code. And you'd better start with filling the store.js file. And enrich its content with getters, mutations (and maybe actions if you need). Check docs: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why but the files are empty. Here's the code working: https://codesandbox.io/s/52r5ow955l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting the state in the store like that, that value is only for reading (or mapping). What you should be doing is create a mutate function in your store and call that from your component.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html

(Also: don't code in other languages than English. Also: there is a lot of duplicate code in there, you should try to get rid of that.)

Comment: Hello. I see a lot of examples about mutation, but I can't figure it out by myself a solution...I tried to do it in my sample too, see the store.js file here: https://codesandbox.io/s/52r5ow955l
But I still don't know how could I set the value.

Comment: You should add a mutation like i did here: https://codesandbox.io/s/j220vno429. After that you can do this.$store.commit('setPrimaeiraData', someData) from your component. Also, your getters are not correct please read the docs about vuex.

Comment: I'll improve the code when the logic is done. At this moment I have a lot of comments and some strange variables too, I know.
About your example, how could I call the mutation to change the value? The sample that you make is something that I already seen in docs, but the problem is (same as the docs) IDK how could I call this mutation method to change the value.

Comment: this.$store.commit('NAME_OF_MUTATION', yourData) (you can later on look at how to use mapMutations, but for now this should work)

Comment: @Andronicus How is "create a mutate function in your store and call that from your component." not an answer to "How could I get and set values with Vuex?".

Comment: @Andonicus Apologies, i now see that if you were to skip the text with the answer to OP's question, it would indeed be a link-only answer. My bad.

Comment: "Don't code in other languages than English" is a bad take. You don't know their situation, who they're working with and what resources are available.

Answer (score 3):

You need getters, mutations, actions, etc. Setting the store's variables like you are currently doing is wrong.

Here's an example of how to update a variable in your store. If you have the following variable:

```js
const defaults = {
  loading: true
}
```

Then you need a function within your store which mutates that data, something like this:

```js
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: Object.assign({}, defaults),
  mutations: {
    updateLoading(state, loading) {
      state.loading = loading
    }
  },
  actions: {
    updateLoading({ commit }, loading) {
      commit('updateLoading', loading)
    }
  }
}
```

In order to call this action (which will mutate the data) from a component, you can do it in a number of ways - my personal preference would be something like this:

```js
<template>{{some stuff}}</template>

<script>
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'

// Change out 'common' for wherever your store is kept.
// I like to split out my store into modules to keep things separate
// In this case, I would have a file called /src/store/common.js
const { mapActions } = createNamespacedHelpers('common')

export default {
  ......... // name, components, data, etc
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['updateLoading']),
    getData() {  // function which calls updateLoading
      this.updateLoading(true);
      ........ // do some stuff
      this.updateLoading(false);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>{{some style}}</style>
```

Of course, if you are just passing data from one page to the next in a linear flow you can always just use props/query parameters/cookies/whatever to pass the data around. Vuex is great but not always necessary (whether it is or isn't necessary in your case is up to you though).

Comment: Hello, Thank for your help. I'm trying to apply your solution, but I'm facing an error in this part, when I get "variable declaration expected"
```const default = {
  loading: true
}```

Comment: Hi, if I remember correctly I believe I followed [this Wiki](https://github.com/prograhammer/vue-pizza/wiki/Vuex) when learning about Vuex for myself (no affiliation). It might be worthwhile having a click around that repo and similar repos to see how it's used in context of a full app.

Comment: The specific example I outlined in my answer was actually from an app I wrote when teaching myself Vue not too long ago. If you want to explore that, it's on my GitHub: [here's my store](https://github.com/james-work-account/vue-frontend/tree/45f68eda7c24eb5170947ac065f941382bbc5225/src/store); [here's where I used it](https://github.com/james-work-account/vue-frontend/blob/45f68eda7c24eb5170947ac065f941382bbc5225/src/features/home/main.vue). Have a click around and see if that helps. Obvious disclaimer: I _am_ affiliated with those links, as they are links to my own GitHub repo.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the other solution is working. At lunch I'll read your github too to check if there's a better way to do what I want.